# WRT54GL hanged today

Tags: wireless-router, wrt54g

The router, I brought not very long ago, hanged today. At first the web pages started to skip loading few images and iframes, then it got slowly worse, till only IM was working.

Ping, traceroute went silent, and I decided it must be the router this time. Tried to access web interface via https over wireless G (WPA2), but most requests resulted in timeout, and few that went through to basic page, showed corrupted page.

In the end I switched the router on and off, and now it's smooth again.

Is this a known issue with WRT54GL? And is there a way to script a reset event in cases when web interface is completely unusable?

Comment: So this has been working non stop since between "not very long ago," and now?  Are we talking about days, weeks, months, or years?

Comment: If the router won't respond without a reset, "And is there a way to script a reset event in cases when web interface is completely unusable," isn't possible unless it is on a computer connected UPS that you can turn off individual plugs with a script.  Write a script that polls SNMP in the router.  When there is no SNMP response, reset the plug in the UPS.

Comment: Month or so, without a reboot. Still, the router is not easily accessible and I'd love to have some telnet or something script ready just in case.

Comment: Was Telnet functional (you said the web interface was down)?

Comment: The packet loss is the enemy, I guess I could write a direct post request to restart page, as it's not like the requests never go through, they just timeout while displaying to administration page. But maybe there is a direct remote command prompt, it's Linux underneath after all.

Comment: The requests sometimes went through, each 50th would load a page, although slightly corrupt, but navigating to reset page was impossible.

Comment: What firmware are you running? I'm using DD-WRT v24-sp1 (yeah, old, I know) and I've never had this issue.

Comment: Firmware Version: v4.30.7, from the box. Hmm, I can't find where is the reboot page anymore. There is this link in history https://ip_address_of_router/restart.cgi, but it didn't worked when I tried while the router was hanging.

Comment: If packets are being dropped in a network by a router, there is too much traffic for the configuration, or the router is busy in another process. If you aren't changing the configuration, where is the extra traffic coming from, or what process is hanging the router?  I ask this because you may want to see if there is traffic you aren't expecting occurring.  If not, firmware is absolutely a viable concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just about to write what Broam said. Also, you will be able to telnet/ssh into your router with most custom firmware. I know at least dd-wrt and tomato supports it.

Comment: I guess, it's a research time then.

Comment: Actually, Broam's comment was written before mine. Imo, he answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a fine opportunity to replace the firmware with your favorite third-party firmware, e.g., DD-WRT, OpenWRT, Tomato, etc.